# Google Drive Ruby API won't return spreadsheet contents as csv

Tags: ruby, google-sheets, google-drive-api

I am trying to write a Ruby script to automatically download a spreadsheet from Google Drive in csv format.  The resulting file is always empty.

Interestingly enough, if I download it in .xlsx format, I get a file that almost works.  (Excel will open the file, but must repair it first.)

Does anybody see a bug in my code?  (The code below is the 'quickstart.rb' sample code provided by Google with a few modifications at the very end.)

```
require 'google/apis/drive_v3'
require 'googleauth'
require 'googleauth/stores/file_token_store'

require 'fileutils'

OOB_URI = 'urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob'
APPLICATION_NAME = 'Drive API Ruby Quickstart'
CLIENT_SECRETS_PATH = 'client_secret.json'
CREDENTIALS_PATH = File.join(Dir.home, '.credentials',
                             "drive-ruby-quickstart.yaml")
SCOPE = Google::Apis::DriveV3::AUTH_DRIVE

##
# Ensure valid credentials, either by restoring from the saved credentials
# files or intitiating an OAuth2 authorization. If authorization is required,
# the user's default browser will be launched to approve the request.
#
# @return [Google::Auth::UserRefreshCredentials] OAuth2 credentials
def authorize
  FileUtils.mkdir_p(File.dirname(CREDENTIALS_PATH))

  client_id = Google::Auth::ClientId.from_file(CLIENT_SECRETS_PATH)
  token_store = Google::Auth::Stores::FileTokenStore.new(file: CREDENTIALS_PATH)
  authorizer = Google::Auth::UserAuthorizer.new(
      client_id, SCOPE, token_store)
  user_id = 'default'
  credentials = authorizer.get_credentials(user_id)
  if credentials.nil?
    url = authorizer.get_authorization_url(
        base_url: OOB_URI)
    puts "Open the following URL in the browser and enter the " +
             "resulting code after authorization"
    puts url
    code = gets
    credentials = authorizer.get_and_store_credentials_from_code(
        user_id: user_id, code: code, base_url: OOB_URI)
  end
  credentials
end

# Initialize the API
service = Google::Apis::DriveV3::DriveService.new
service.client_options.application_name = APPLICATION_NAME
service.authorization = authorize

response = service.list_files(page_size: 1000, fields: 'nextPageToken, files(id, name)')
budget_sheet = response.files.find {|file| file.name == 'Budget 2012'}


# Make sure the file is found
puts "#{budget_sheet.name} (#{budget_sheet.id})"

# This almost works.  (File foo.xlsx contains data, but Excel complains that it has errors)
service.export_file(budget_sheet.id, 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet', download_dest: '/tmp/foo.xlsx')

# This does not work. It always generates an empty file
service.export_file(budget_sheet.id, 'text/csv', download_dest: '/tmp/foo.csv')
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the library you're using, but based on the sample in their documentation, the [file resource](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files#resource) should include `exportLinks` with the corresponding

```
download_url = file['exportLinks']['application/pdf']
```

Hope this helps!